# How to write DQL query innner join to avoid lazy loading?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

My code:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $result = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('c')                        
                    ->from('BlogHomepageBundle:Comment', 'c')
                    ->innerJoin('BlogHomepageBundle:Post', 'po', 'WITH', 'c.postFk = po.postId')
                    ->getQuery()->getResult();
    foreach ($result as $c) {
        //additional sql query
        echo $c->getPostFk()->getName();
    }
```

It works just fine, but when Im trying to get postFk ( post relate to comment one-to-many relation) I'm getting additional query to db ( lazy loading). Can I avoid this situtation to get all data in one DQL query ? Simple to performe sql query

```
select c.*, p.* from comment as c inner join post as p on c.post_fk = p.post_id
```

I want to use DQL ( not raw sql ).

**EDIT**
I would like to have Objects and access to them like in foreach loop / not scalar data.

Comment: Why do you not use native joins between entities?
Once you define your relations between  Entities you will not have any problems with eager joins.

Comment: what do you mean by native joins?

Comment: Association mappings: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: Will association mappings help with reciving data from db? as I wrote this example is working fine.. only one problem is lazy-loading I want avoid unnecessary data base processes.

Comment: If you define mappings, you can just `->select('c, po')                        
                    ->from('BlogHomepageBundle:Comment', 'c')->innerJoin('c.post', 'po')`->getQuery()->getResult();
This method adds 2 lines of code but it is clear and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifically select a property or a join to avoid lazy loading :

> ->select('c', 'po')

http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-lazy-loading.html

Comment: I did. But than I've got this error

FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Proxies\__CG__\Blog\HomepageBundle\Entity\Post::getPostFk() in ..\Blog\HomepageBundle\Controller\HomepageController.php line 47

Answer (score 1):

I think I found solution @Rpg600 thanks for help.
This is code:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $result = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c', 'po')
            ->from('BlogHomepageBundle:Comment', 'c')
            ->innerJoin('c.postFk', 'po', 'WITH', 'c.postFk = po.postId')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();



    foreach ($result as $c) {
        echo $c->getContent();
        echo $c->getPostFk()->getName();
    }
```